# Issue with link_to in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am a newbie to rail and try to build my first site but face an issue with a link_to in an index page. The link redirect to /recipes.1 instead of /recipes/1.
The show page work when i try /recipes/1.

Index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Recipe") %>
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
  <%= link_to recipe.label, recipe%>
<%end%>
```

route.db

```
get       'recipe'     => 'recipes#show'
get       'recipe'     => 'recipes#new'
post     'recipe'       => 'recipes#create'
resources :users
resources :recipes
```

recipes_controller.rb

```
def index
  @recipes = Recipe.all
end

def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following routes from **routes.rb**:

```
get       'recipe'     => 'recipes#show'
get       'recipe'     => 'recipes#new'
post     'recipe'       => 'recipes#create'
```

The above routes are not required since `resources :recipes` generate all these routes for you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue, i have removed them and it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
   <%= link_to recipe.label, recipe_url(recipe) %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%=link_to recipe.label, recipe_path(recipe)%>
```

Instead of

```
<%= link_to recipe.label, recipe%>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have defined show path twice.
1. in manual defined path

```
get       'recipe'     => 'recipes#show'
```

2. Through

```
resources :recipes
```

If you do `rake routes`, then you will first option create routes for get method with `/recipe` url and appends parameter to it which result in `/recipes.1` path.

Also rails read routes file in **top to bottom** approach. As uses first routes for show method.